# Ebonite rod charged with fur is brought together with an acetate rod charged with silk

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, charge

What would happen if an ebonite rod charged with fur is brought together with an acetate rod charged with silk?

Answer (score 1):

The electrons in fur are much less tightly bound than electrons in ebonite (very strong relative bond, ebonite is at the bottom of the negative **Triboelectric series**, see [[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triboelectric_effect#Triboelectric_series)) and hence ebonite gets a strong relative negative charge [[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triboelectric_effect#Triboelectric_series).

["A material towards the bottom of the Triboelectric series table, when touched to a material near the top of the series, will acquire a more negative charge."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triboelectric_effect#Triboelectric_series)

The electrons in acetate are more tightly bound than electrons in silk and hence the acetate gets a medium relative negative charge (acetate is at about the middle of the negative Triboelectric series [[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triboelectric_effect#Triboelectric_series).

Hence under even test conditions for the two different charged rods (i.e. time and force of rubbing), expect the ebonite rod to be more negatively charged than the acetade rod. Therefore when the two charged rods will be brought together the ebonite rod will be negative combared to the acetate rod which will be relative positive charged.

End result: Attraction.

[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triboelectric_effect#Triboelectric_series) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triboelectric_effect#Triboelectric_series